# How do I get feedback in the Auditorium chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

I am writing a marimba solo and saw that there is a chat room dedicated to giving feedback, namely the auditorium. I posted some information about my composition and a link. I am asking if someone will eventually just come into the chat room to help or if I have to invite someone in?

Just to be clear, I only posted the message about an hour ago so I don't expect that anyone will reply soon. I just want confirmation that I understand how to use the auditorium. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're correct that people eventually drop in and see your post. I saw it, for example, but haven't had a chance to comment yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this’s exactly the sort of thing [The Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium) is for, thanks for posting!

Unfortunately, the chat rooms aren’t used as often as they once were, so you may have to wait a number of days (or longer) for a response.  But there are some of us who do check in regularly (or at least every now and again).

Here (our local meta) is also the right place to ask about how the chat rooms work, so you’re doing everything right.